# max of limit cardinals smaller than a successor cardinal bigger than $\aleph_\omega$

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

This is the statment i want to proove : 
if $k$ is a successor cardinal bigger than $\aleph_{\omega}$ then there is a max of $\{\lambda < k | \lambda \text{ is a limit cardinal}\}$. 
Assuming (AC), if $k \geq \omega$ then $k^{+}$ is regular, so we can assume that $k$ is regular. I've found this argument but i'm not sure that it's correct : 
By contradiction, if there is no max, then the union of all $\lambda$ limit smaller than $k$ is a successor cardinal $\leq k$. But a successor cardinal is regular, so it cannot be reach by this union : a contradiction. So there must be a max. Am I right?

Comment: As phrased, it's not at all clear that this union is not regular. Hence your argument is incomplete/doesn't work.

Comment: Elaborating on Stefan's comment, it is (hopefully) consistent with ZFC that there are [uncountable regular limit cardinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inaccessible_cardinal). There is a crucial property that a union of limits with no maximal element has, though, which a successor cardinal doesn't ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $\rho = \bigcup \{ \lambda < \kappa \mid \lambda \text{ is a limit cardinal } \}$. $\rho$ is a nonempty union of cardinals and hence itself a cardinal. If you can show that $\rho$ is a limit cardinal, you're done.

Comment: Note that $\rho \le \mu$, where $\mu^+ = \kappa$. (The proof that $\rho$ is a limit cardinal doesn't depend on this. But if $\kappa$ where not a successor cardinal, we could have that $\rho = \kappa$.)

Comment: if i suppose, by contraddiction, that $\rho = \lambda_1^{+}$ i.e. $\rho$ is a successor cardinal, then $\lambda_1 \in \rho = \cup \{\lambda < k | \lambda limit cardinal \} $ there must be a $\lambda_2$ such that $\lambda_1 < \lambda_2 < \rho$, so there is a cardinal between $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_1^{+} = \rho$. contraddiction! So $\rho$ is a limit cardinal. Am I right?

Comment: @M.Bailetti That nearly works. We don't know that $\lambda_1$ is a limit cardinal but that isn't needed at all. No matter what $\lambda_1$ is, there must be a limit cardinal $\lambda_1 < \lambda_2 < \rho$ (as $\rho$ is the supremum, as an ordinal, of these limit cardinals) -- which is, of course, absurd.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much! In this proof we don't need AC, do we?

Comment: @M.Bailetti That's right. We don't need choice, as long as we assume that $\kappa$ is an ordinal, i.e. well-orderable. In particular, the proof would work even if $\kappa$ were singular (which is possible in the abscence of choice).

Comment: Are there cardinals that are not ordinals ? The definition that i have for "$k$ is a cardinal" is " an ordinal that is not in bijection with any ordinal $\alpha < k$".

Comment: @M.Bailetti Without choice, there are sets which are in no bijection to an ordinal. They are, modulo bijection, also considered cardinals. The $\aleph$-numbers are then those cardinals which are in bijection to some ordinal (or equivalenty those that can be well-ordered).

Comment: Ok, i wasn't considering those sets as cardinals. Thank you, again.

Answer (score 1):

Choice has nothing to do with this. The $\aleph$ numbers are defined the same. Of course, for non-$\aleph$ cardinals there is an issue for what would be a successor, or limit, and so on. So let's ignore that issue and focus on $\aleph$ cardinals.

You can easily prove this by induction, noting that successor cardinals are exactly those whose $\aleph$ index is a successor ordinal. So the question is reduced to limit ordinals below infinite successor ordinals, and this question is easier to grasp.